# How to create a fully connected(matrix) layer with vector input

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I am trying to replace last fully connected layer of size 4096/2048 with a matrix of size 100x300 with previous fc layer output of 2048.

[image: something of this sort : something of this sort]

I've tried

1. 2D convolution - to map from 2048 --> 100x300 (Which is not realizable)
2. Intermediate projections :
       2048 --> 100
       [100x1] X [1x300] --> [100x300] (possible but complicated)

I am looking for a simple and effective solution with least linear transformations.

[image: This is desired]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tf.reshape()` method ([tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)) to reshape `(2048)` dimensional tensor to `(100,300)`. Here's one way to do this:

```
input1 = tf.reshape(input1, [100,300], name="reshaped_tensor")
```

If you're not using TensorFlow but using Numpy, here's an implementation:

```
input1 = np.array(input1)
input1 = np.reshape(input1, (100,300))
```

Note: You might want to follow up this layer with `tf.nn.conv2d` layers to "densify" the sparse matrix/values obtained from the above step.

Comment: Thanks, I've represented the 2048 to 300*100=30000 and reshaped to 100x300, and this worked

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Thanks for contributing!  *(The original question has been flagged as unclear--clearly it wasn't for you, so please feel free to edit the question to ensure it doesn't get closed by the community.)*